# how to set an environment variable when run - az container app compose create

Tags: docker-compose, azure-container-apps

It seems when my docker compose yml is run via "az containerapp compose create", environment variables are not picked up. Is there a way I can set an env variable so the command picks it up?

I'm seeing this error:

> ERROR: The following field(s) are either invalid or missing. Invalid value: "${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}/sample-blazorapp": could not parse reference: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}/sample-blazorapp: template.containers.blazorapp.image.

I have set the variable with: export DOCKER_REGISTRY="myregistry"

And when I echo $DOCKER_REGISTRY, the value is returned. So in the bash session it is set (I tried powershell first, I thought that was the issue because $(envvar-) is bash syntax, however the error is the same.)

This is what I have in my compose file (alignment is correct in the file):

```
blazorapp:
container_name: "blazorapp"
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sample-blazorapp
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: BlazorApp/BlazorApp/Dockerfile
depends_on:
  - redis
ports:
  - "55000:443"
```

If I explicitly set the image name, i.e. not use an env var, then it works. i.e. this change to the image line works:

```
image: myregistry/sample-blazorapp
```

I also tried adding the forward slash, this makes no difference (as expected, it works fine without the slash when running docker compose up).

I can set it explicitly but that would be annoying. I feel like I'm missing something. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered the issue, I was missing a colon.

Does not work (produces the error described in the question):

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sample-blazorapp
```

Also does not work:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-mydefault}sample-blazorapp
```

Add the magic : in and it works:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY:-}sample-blazorapp
```

Also works:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY:-mydefault}sample-blazorapp
```

Answer (score 0):

If the image is defined like this into you docker compose file:

```
image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}sample-blazorapp
```

then you must export using a slash at the end of the value:

```
export DOCKER_REGISTRY="myregistry/"
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, although you are probably correct that I need to add the trailing slash, the main problem is the environment variable is not being picked up in the context of the docker-compose file at all. It's just reading {DOCKER_REGISTRY} as is, as a string.